# How to detect if shift has been released?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to run a function when the shift key is released.

I know the shift key can be detected with something like:

```
$(window).bind("keydown keyup", function(ev) { ... });
```

It works very well for detecting key combinations (e.g. `shift+a`). Problem is, if you want to detect the shift key itself, this triggers a `keydown` with `ev.shiftKey=false`, `ev.which=16` and a `keyup` with `ev.shiftKey=true`, `ev.which=16`. I've tried to attach an event to this combination on `keyup`, but this fail in a very subtle way when both shift keys are pressed: for the second shift key you get both `keyup/keydown` with `true,16` and then you get another `keyup` with `true,16` when the first shift key is released.

Is there any clean way to do this? Or should I just ignore the two shift key case?

Comment: Yeah, the obvious way to deal with it is to increment a variable when shift goes down and decrement it when shift comes up. Unless that variable equals zero, you can assume shift is pressed. That said, even though it's not a very difficult solution to implement, I don't any reason why someone would press both.

Answer (score 1):

Someone pressing both SHIFT keys at the same time is improbable, unless they are intentionally trying to break your application. You can't design (**read**: *waste time*) coding edge cases, when 99% of your users in this case would never be pressing both keys.

Your logic for determining key presses is sound. Set a variable and increment/decrement it based on the presses, and if it equals 0, then they've got nothing pressed. Presto bammo.

EDIT: OR just do what Brian said in his comment! :)